# Why was Lemiel healed from his wounds when he was brought back from his statue form?

Tags: black-clover

When Lemiel was sealed in his statue form hundreds of years ago, he was wounded. But after returning to life, his wounds arent seen anymore and he looks healed.

Why was Lemiel healed from his wounds when he was brought back from his statue form?

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion it is because he has been sealed by nero A.K.A secre swallowtail by using a magic stone and probably also because it has been a very long time since he was sealed and the wound healed by itself

Answer (score 1):

From what i saw in the series, it appeared that he was turned into stone when he became a statue. His wounds never actually healed, they were just unable to bleed as he is now a statue. That's why his arm didn't bleed when cut off during the battle in the shadow palace.